# Passing 2D jagged array to webservice

Tags: c#, arrays, web-services, delphi

I have webservice wrote in C# whichc allows me to communicate between two systems. I'd like to one of methods accept `ClassName[][]` as one (and only) parameter.
This method is defined as follows:

```
namespace WebService
{
    public enum DocumentType { documentType1, documentType2, documentType3 };

    public class MyClass
    {
        private int? id;
        private DocumentType documentType;

        public int? Id
        {
            get { return id; }
            set { id = value; }
        }

        public DocumentType DocumentType
        {
            get { return documentType; }
            set { documentType = value; }
        }

        public MyClass()
        {
            this.id = null;
        }
        public MyClass(int id, DocumentType documentType)
        {
            this.Id = id;
            this.DocumentType = documentType;
        }
    }

    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IPisma
    {
        [OperationContract]
        Tuple<MyClass, bool>[][] WebserviceMethod(MyClass[][] myClassArray);
    }
}
```

Call is made with this code wrote in Delphi:

```
procedure Call();
var
  webServiceParameter: ArrayOfArrayOfMyClass;
begin
  //init parameter and fill with test data
  SetLength(webServiceParameter, 2, 2);
  webServiceParameter[0][0] := MyClass.Create();
  webServiceParameter[0][0].Id := 1621806;
  webServiceParameter[0][0].DocumentType := DocumentType.documentType1;
  webServiceParameter[0][1] := MyClass.Create();
  webServiceParameter[0][1].Id := 564194;
  webServiceParameter[0][1].DocumentType := DocumentType.documentType2;
  webServiceParameter[1][0] := MyClass.Create();
  webServiceParameter[1][0].Id := 1623444;
  webServiceParameter[1][0].DocumentType := DocumentType.documentType1;
  webServiceParameter[1][1] := MyClass.Create();
  webServiceParameter[1][1].Id := 1624682;
  webServiceParameter[1][1].DocumentType := DocumentType.documentType1;

  //create webservice object and call method
  GetIPisma(False, '', HTTPRIO).WebserviceMethod(webServiceParameter);
end;
```

Tried to check what is actually sent to webservice and in `HTTPRIO.BeforeExecution` event and SOAPRequest has following data in it:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body xmlns:NS1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WebService">
        <WebserviceMethod xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
            <myClassArray>
                <ArrayOfMyClass>
                    <MyClass xsi:type="NS1:MyClass">
                        <Id xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WebService">1621806</Id>
                        <DocumentType xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WebService">documentType1</DocumentType>
                    </MyClass>
                    <MyClass xsi:type="NS1:MyClass">
                        <Id xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WebService">564194</Id>
                        <DocumentType xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WebService">documentType2</DocumentType>
                    </MyClass>
                </ArrayOfMyClass>
                <ArrayOfMyClass>
                    <MyClass xsi:type="NS1:MyClass">
                        <Id xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WebService">1623444</Id>
                        <DocumentType xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WebService">documentType1</DocumentType>
                    </MyClass>
                    <MyClass xsi:type="NS1:MyClass">
                        <Id xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WebService">1624682</Id>
                        <DocumentType xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WebService">documentType1</DocumentType>
                    </MyClass>
                </ArrayOfMyClass>
            </myClassArray>
        </WebserviceMethod>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Within implementation of `WebserviceMethod` parameters `myClassArray` length is 0. Tried few things like wrapping one of dimensions into another class but with no success. Intersting fact is that when I try to pass 1D array of MyClass (MyClass[] myClassArray) everything works fine and xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <WebserviceMethod xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
            <myClassArray>
                <MyClass xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WebService" xsi:type="MyClass">
                    <Id>1621806</Id>
                    <DocumentType>documentType1</DocumentType>
                </MyClass>
                <MyClass xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WebService" xsi:type="MyClass">
                    <Id>162186</Id>
                    <DocumentType>documentType1</DocumentType>
                </MyClass>
            </myClassArray>
        </WebserviceMethod>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Result of `WebserviceMethod` is acquired without problems.

Is it even possible to pass multidimensional jagged array to webservice?